# Remove from array if not present in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var allowedIds = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004];
var idsToCheck = [1000, 1001, 1005, 1006];
```

I'm looking to find a way to remove 1005 & 1006 from arrayToCheck as those ids are not in the allowedIds array

any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: do a array `.filter` on idstocheck.. you can filter out the values that is not present in allowedIds by using the `.indexOf`.

Answer (score 11):

You can iterate over `idsToCheck` using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out all ids which are not in `allowedIds`. For example:

```
const checkedIds = idsToCheck.filter(id => allowedIds.includes(id));
```

Note: using ES6 features: `arrow functions` and `Array.prototype.includes()`. To use it in older browsers check for compatibility.

Here is an alternative implementation with better browser compatiblity:

```
var checkedIds = idsToCheck.filter(function(id) {
  return allowedIds.indexOf(id) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Both of these are very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You should mark this question as correct, since it worked for you.