# How to remove object in array if not present in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove an object in array if not present in another array.
I tried to search and found similar question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787064/remove-from-array-if-not-present-in-another-array) but have a different array source.

Here is the example from link above :

```js
var check = [1, 2, 3];
var allowed = [1];

var filtered = check.filter(function(item) {
  return allowed.indexOf(item) > -1;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Example above remove number in array `check` if not present in array `allowed`. In my case the source array contain an object like example below :

```js
var check = [
    {
        name: 'Peter',
        location: 'florida'
    },
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'California'
    }
];

var allowed = [
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'Boston'
    }
];

var filtered = check.filter(function(item) {
  return allowed.indexOf(item.name) > -1;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

I tried to run the code and the result is an empty array.

Result i expect :

```
[
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'California'
    }
]
```

Anyone can please help me to make the result as i expect?

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: You need nested `filter`, not `indexOf`

Comment: Right now `return allowed.indexOf(item.name) > -1;` is checking if a 'person object' is equal to the name

Comment: try allowed.indexOf(item) > -1

Comment: @NilsFett you can't....the two objects are not same reference

Comment: Part of your problem is that for your allowed, you have both the name and location in one object. This indicates (to me) that you need to match BOTH fields. If you want to match either, you should have two `allowed` arrays: One for names and one for locations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var check = [{
    name: 'Peter',
    location: 'florida'
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    location: 'California'
  }
];

var allowed = [{
  name: 'Robert',
  location: 'Boston'
}];

var res = check.filter(function(cItem) {
  return allowed.find(function(aItem) {
    return cItem.name === aItem.name
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can map `allowed` to just contain the criteria that you are looking for (name):

```
var allowed = [{
    name: 'Robert',
    location: 'Boston'
}]
.map(obj => obj.name);
```

That will create an array of just names which is easier to test the `indexOf`

Example:

```js
var check = [{
    name: 'Peter',
    location: 'florida'
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    location: 'California'
  }
];

var allowed = [{
  name: 'Robert',
  location: 'Boston'
}]
.map(obj => obj.name);

var filtered = check.filter(function(item) {
  return allowed.indexOf(item.name) > -1;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to check against the item names in the `allowed` array.
Right now you're checking against the items in the allowed array, which type is an object.

Here's the problem: `return allowed.indexOf(item.name) > -1;`

Maybe this approach helps:

```js
var check = [
    {
        name: 'Peter',
        location: 'florida'
    },
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'California'
    }
];

var allowed = [
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'Boston'
    }
];

function containsName(name, array){
  return array.find(item => item.name === name);
}

var filtered = check.filter(function(item) {
  return containsName(item.name, allowed)
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The following intersect function would intersect any key on any given array of objects:

```js
var check = [
    { name:'Peter', location:'florida' },
    { name:'Robert', location:'California'}
];

var allowed = [
    { name:'Robert', location:'Boston' }
];

function intersect(check, allowed) {
    var allowed_map = allowed.reduce(function(map, obj) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            if (!map[key]) {
                map[key] = [];
            }
            map[key].push(obj[key]);
        });
        return map;
    }, {});


    return check.filter(function(item) {
        return Object.keys(item).find(function(key) {
            return allowed_map[key].indexOf(item[key]) != -1;
        })
    });
}

var filtered = intersect(check, allowed);

var allowed2 = [{ name:'Bob', location:'California' }];
var filtered2 = intersect(check, allowed2);

console.log('filtered',filtered);
console.log('filtered2',filtered2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches depending on what you need.

- Dirty Check
- Specific Attribute Check
- Nested Object Check

#### Dirty Check

For a dirty check where the objects will have the same memory reference on both arrays you can do the following.

```js
var firstPerson = {
    name: 'Peter',
    location: 'florida'
}
var secondPerson = {
    name: 'Robert',
    location: 'California'
}

var allowed = [secondPerson];
var check = [firstPerson, secondPerson];

var result = check.filter(item => allowed.includes(item));

console.log(result);
```

#### Specific Attribute Check

For an specific attribute check you can use `find` and compare the `check` and `allowed`, by an attribute like `name` or `location`

```js
var check = [
    {
        name: 'Peter',
        location: 'florida'
    },
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'California'
    }
];

var allowed = [
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: 'Boston'
    }
];


var result = check.filter(checkPerson => allowed.find(allowPerson => allowPerson.name === checkPerson.name));

console.log(result);
```

#### Nested Object Check

For a nested object check you would require to check the items recursively, I use this utility I created some time ago called [`deepCompare`](https://gist.github.com/garyvh2/e0773db75310def1450db3686070c109#file-deep-compare-js), is an alternative to Lodash's [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) that only weights 880B

```js
var check = [
    {
        name: 'Peter',
        location: {
            street: "fridtjof nansens vei 8511",
            city: "ågotnes",
            state: "buskerud",
            postcode: "8766",
            coordinates: {
                latitude: "50.4828",
                longitude: "-84.6920"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: {
            street: "schillerstraße 69",
            city: "velburg",
            state: "saarland",
            postcode: 72100,
            coordinates: {
                latitude: "30.4655",
                longitude: "9.1938"
            }
        }
    }
];

var allowed = [
    {
        name: 'Robert',
        location: {
            street: "schillerstraße 69",
            city: "velburg",
            state: "saarland",
            postcode: 72100,
            coordinates: {
                latitude: "30.4655",
                longitude: "9.1938"
            }
        }
    }
];


var result = check.filter(checkPerson => allowed.some(allowPerson => deepCompare(checkPerson, allowPerson)));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
/**
 * Deep Compare
 * @param { * } value first entry value
 * @param { * } other second entry value
 * @param { Boolean } sorted Sort any array before deep comparison
 */
const deepCompare = (value, other, sorted) => {
  /**
   * Compare possible primitives
   * Object.is works like `===` but additionally differes positive from negative values
   * I.E:
   *  Object.is(-0, 0) // False
   *  -0 === 0 // True
   */
  if (Object.is(value, other)) return true;
  /**
   * Check if either value is undefined or the constructor is different for each value
   * given the case return false
   */
  if (!value || !other || value.constructor !== other.constructor) return false;
  /**
   * Check Object and Array deep comparisons
   */
  switch (value.constructor) {
    case Array:
      /**
       * Check if both values have the same amount of items
       * if they don't immediatelly omit the comparison and return false
       */
      if (value.length === other.length) { return deepArrayCompare(value, other, sorted); }
      return false;
    case Object:
      /**
       * Check if both values have the same amount of keys
       * if they don't immediatelly omit the comparison and return false
       */
      if (Object.keys(value).length === Object.keys(other).length) { return deepObjectCompare(value, other, sorted); }
      return false;
  }
  return false;
};
/**
 * Deep Object Compare
 * @param { * } value first entry value
 * @param { * } other second entry value
 *
 * 'deepArrayCompare(Object.keys(value), Object.keys(other), sorted)'
 * This checks that both objects have the same keys
 * I.E:
 *  deepArrayCompare(Object.keys({ a: 1, b: 2, c:3 }), Object.keys({ a: 10, b: 22, c: 54 }), true) // True
 *  deepArrayCompare(Object.keys({ a: 1, b: 2, c:3 }), Object.keys({ g: 1, f: 2, d: 3 }), true) // False
 *
 * 'Object.keys(value).every(key => deepCompare(value[key], other[key]))'
 * This iterates on each key of the object over a 'every' comparison and performs a deepCompare on both values
 *
 */
const deepObjectCompare = (value, other) => deepArrayCompare(Object.keys(value), Object.keys(other), true) && Object.keys(value).every(key => deepCompare(value[key], other[key]));
/**
 * Deep Array Compare
 * @param { * } value first entry value
 * @param { * } other second entry value
 * @param { Boolean } sorted Sort any array before deep comparison
 *
 * '(sorted && value.sort(), sorted && other.sort(), ...)'
 * This manages the optional sorting through Comma Operator
 *
 * 'value.every((item, index) => deepCompare(item, other[index]))'
 * This performs the deepComparison of values between both arrays
 */
const deepArrayCompare = (value, other, sorted) => (sorted && value.sort(), sorted && other.sort(), value.every((item, index) => deepCompare(item, other[index])));
</script>
```